# Kubernetes ingress timeout annotations not getting applied to the Nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Edit: Now working. We do not what caused it to not work before.

We are trying to set a different timeout for one of our downstream services (location) for our nginx controller. We are using the annotations in the ingress documented
[here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-timeouts). We can see that our other annotation are taking effect on our service, but the timeouts does not work.

This a snippet from our service ingress config,

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: namespace
  name: ingress-name
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "300"
```

In the **nginx.conf** for each location block/service we can see that the timeout values does not change.

```yaml
proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
proxy_send_timeout 60s;
proxy_read_timeout 60s;
```

As we understand according to the source code the default values above will be set if these annotations are not set.

- [Ingress annotation proxy, main.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/b1c8e3047ba31d7ea78f6e0915d187db75230ba5/internal/ingress/annotations/proxy/main.go#L138)
- [Nginx template](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/b1c8e3047ba31d7ea78f6e0915d187db75230ba5/rootfs/etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl#L1270)

We have also read this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2007) and checked so that we have not made the same mistakes as they are discussing.

---

- We are using version [v0.40.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/controller-v0.40.0) of Nginx helm chart to install Nginx
- Our kubernetes version is 1.19.7.
- We have not changed the default nginx annotation namespace so it should be *nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io*

Comment: I tried the same annotations on one our existing ingress resource, and it seems to be working for me. In the `nginx.conf` of the nginx controller pod, inside the server block of the host for which I made the change, I can see both the `proxy_send_timeout` & `proxy_read_timeout` set to `300s`. Mind it, it's changed only for server block/host for which I made the change and not the others. I hope you're looking at the write place.

Comment: @Pontus Thomé does that rock'n rolla comment answers your question? Or do you still have an issue with that ingress?

Comment: Hi,

@rock'nrolla It should be setting these settings in the "location block" as far as we can see. So that it only affects our specific application. If you check the [Ingress Template code](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/b1c8e3047ba31d7ea78f6e0915d187db75230ba5/rootfs/etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl#L1270)

Comment: @Jakub We still need help.